# Замена спецсимволов на картинку

Tags: php

Есть поле photo, в котором хранятся картинки к статье, разделенные пробелом.
Есть поле content, в которое при вставке картинки заносится спецсимволы #фото#
Сколько картинок, столько и #фото#

Как при выводе статьи заменить #фото# на `<img src="путь_к_картинке" alt="" />`

Comment: А зачем хранить в базе и картинки, и "маркеры" (*спецсимволы #фото#*)?

Comment: сам не понимаю) я устроился на работу, а тут до меня кто-то напортачил, поэтому нужно сейчас искать решение

Comment: Как определить к какому именно изображению относиться тег #фото#? Они как-то связаны?

Comment: до этого код был закрыт, переношу сайт на новый сервер

Comment: > никак не связаны

Ого... Тут даже два бубна в руках будет мало )) За что-то ж надо зацепиться?

Comment: Может картинки лежат в той же последовательности, что и теги #фото#?

Answer (score 1):

Складываем в одну кучу коллекцию изображений. Приходимся по тексту статьи и при встрече тега #фото# заменяем его на соответствующее по позиции изображение: для первого тега — первая картинка, для второго — вторая...

```
<?php

class Article
{
    public function Article($title, $content, $photo) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->photo = $photo;
        $this->content = $content;
    }
}

$news = array();
$news[] = new Article("Article#1", "Some text #фото# and #фото# and #фото#", "Img#1 Img#2 Img#3");
$news[] = new Article("Article#2", "Some text #фото# and #фото# and #фото#", "Img#1 Img#2 Img#3");

// Выводим новости
foreach($news as $item): ?>
    <h1 class="biggest"><?php echo $item->title; ?></h1>
    <div>
    <?php
    // Делим строку с фото на элементы массива по пробелах
    $photos = explode(' ', $item->photo);
    // Заменяем каждый тег #фото# на соответствующее ему изображение
    foreach($photos as $photo) {
        $html_photo = '<img src="'.$photo.'" />';
        $item->content = preg_replace("/\#фото\#/", $html_photo, $item->content, 1);
    }  
    echo $item->content; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: А если пусть к картинке будет включать в себя пробел?

Comment: Делите их через directory separator.
А вообще, если правильно, то необходимо хранить в БД каждую картинку в виде отдельной записи таблицы. В PHP они соответственно будут представлены в виде массива строк.

Ответ обновил. Работает со строкой путей-к-файлам-картинок-разделенных-пробелами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто и красиво заменить все вхождения строки через [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$text = 'В этом тексте есть #фото# и еще несколько #фото##фото#, #фото#';
$photos = [1,2,3,4]; // кол-во должно совпадать соответственно
reset($photos); // смещам указатель массива замен на начало
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/#фото#/ui', // нужный шаблон
    function($matches) use (&$photos) { // передаем массив замен по ссылке
        return '<img src="' . each($photos)['value'] . '" />'; // возвращаем на каждую замену следующей элемент из массива замен
    },
    $text
);
```